# Converting "Long Shadow" SASS mixin to Less

Tags: css, sass, less

I try to rewrite sass mixin for generation long text-shadow
http://codepen.io/awesomephant/pen/mAxHz
to less mixin

```
.long-shadow(@type, @color, @length, @fadeout: true, @skew: false, @direction: right){


 @shadow : '';
  .if @skew == false or @type == text{
    .if @direction == right {@
      @for @i from 0 to @length - 1 {
        @shadow: @shadow + @i + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' + @color + ',';
      }
    }
    .if @direction == left {@
      @for @i from 0 to @length - 1 {
        @shadow: @shadow + @i * -1 + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' + @color + ',';
       }
      }
     }

   .if @fadeout == true{
    @for @i from 1 to @length - 1 {
      .if @type == text or @skew == false{
        .if @direction == right{
          @shadow: @shadow + @i + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' +       rgba(@color, 1 - @i / @length) + ',';
        }
        .if @direction == left{
          @shadow: @shadow + @i * -1 + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' +       rgba(@color, 1 - @i / @length) + ',';
        }
      }
      .if (@type == box) and @skew == true{
        .if @direction == right {
          @shadow: @shadow + @i + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' + @i * .2 + 'px ' + rgba(@color, 1 - @i / @length) + ',';
        }
        .if @direction == left {
          @shadow: @shadow + @i * -1 + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' + @i * .2 + 'px ' + rgba(@color, 1 - @i / @length) + ',';
        }
      }
  }
  @shadow: @shadow + @length + 'px ' + @length + 'px 0 ' + rgba(@color, 0);
 }
 .if @fadeout == false{
   .if @skew == true and ( @type == box ){
     @for @i from 0 to @length - 1 {
            @shadow: @shadow + @i + 'px ' + @i + 'px 0 ' + @i * .1 + 'px ' + @color + ',';
      }
   }
    @shadow: @shadow + @length + 'px ' + @length + 'px 0 ' + rgba(0,0,0,0);
 }
 @shadow: unquote(@shadow);
  .if @type == 'box' {box-shadow: @shadow;}
  .if @type == 'text' {text-shadow: @shadow;}
}
```

but it doesn't work.
I get an error even at the first line

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input
in style.less on line 2255, column 13:

2254
2255.long-shadow(@type, @color, @length, @fadeout: 'true', @skew: 'false', @direction: 'right'){
2256  @shadow : '';
```

Can please someone to help me with it?

Comment: try http://nicoespeon.com/en/2013/06/convert-sass-project-into-less/

Comment: @cimmanon this question requires knowledge of SASS, Less and CSS so I have restored all original tags.

Comment: It wouldn't require *any* knowledge of Sass if you'd simply asked questions like "how do I do an if statement in Less" or "How do I do a loop with Less".  The way you currently have your question phrased, it is useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in short, beside the very basic language statements like variable and mixin declarations, SCSS and Less are vastly different languages in fact. So when it comes to more advanced stuff like variable scope and lifetime, iterative and conditional structures etc. etc. there's no straight-forward conversion between them. 
Furthermore, since this particular mixin is also an almost perfect example of "spaghetti code", it is actually much more easy to write such mixin from scratch rather than try to convert it "line by line":

```
@import "for";

.long-shadow(@type, @color, @length, @fadeout: true, @scew: false, @direction: right) {
    .-() {
        @dir:  1px;
        @offset: 0;
        @s: (.5px * @i);
        @a: (1 - @i / @length);
        @c: fade(@color, (100% * alpha(@color) * @a * @a));
    }
    .-() when (@direction = left) {@dir: -1px}
    .-() when (@type = box)       {@offset: 1}
    .-() when (@scew = false)     {@s: ;}
    .-() when (@type = text)      {@s: ;}
    .-() when (@fadeout = false)  {@c: @color}

    .for(0, (@length - 1)); .-each(@i) {
        .-();
        @x: (@dir * (@i + @offset));
        @y: (1px  * (@i + @offset));
        @{type}-shadow+: @x @y 0 @s @c;
    }
}

usage {
    .long-shadow(text, red,  4, true, false, right);
    .long-shadow(box,  blue, 4, false, true, left);
}
```

See also this [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/Bkdgp).
It is not exactly compatible with the original mixin, for instance:

- the mixin accepts only unquoted parameters (e.g. `box` and `true` instead of `'box'` and  `'true'`)
- uses slightly different handling of `fadeout` (could be better though, see P.P.S. below)
- does not disable `fadeout` for the `text` type (seems like unnecessary limitation)
- produces different `scew` size

So it's up to you to make further modifications if you need an exact clone.

P.S. Yep, and the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/master/src/for.less) to the imported `"for"` goody.

P.P.S. Btw., there's better fading out method with more natural result. See this [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/hLdKB)