# Is there any possibility to build objects in Less?

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

At the moment I tried to build mixins for less, but it seems to be more complicated than expected. For example, I tried to build an if condition and my header looks like this:

```
.ifClauses(
   @checkParam,
   @conditions:{
    isnumber(@checkParam),
    ispercentage(@checkParam),
    ispixel(@checkParam)
   },
   @thens:{
    .first(){height:@checkParam * 1px;},
    .second(){height:@checkParam;},
    .third(){height:@checkParam;}
   }
)
```

I know that the arrays were defined like:

```
@array: first,second,third;
```

.

Maybe I could use this as an object so to say, how can I write the array to the mixins params when the params were divided by commas?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you fully but you can use `extract(@array, 1)` to extract just the first value from the comma separated string.

Comment: It depends on on how you're going to use this "objects". In general case both mixin/rulesets (incl. detached) can be interpreted as sort of OOP types and objects (to a certain degree). However for you particular case (emulating `if` statement?) strict "object-like" abstraction is not what really fits the best. For examples of such `if` emulations see: [1](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1894#issuecomment-35833238), [2](https://github.com/pixelass/homeless) etc.

Comment: The rest depends on what all these `1st, 2nd, 3rd etc` are supposed to mean. In other words it might be wise to provide more details about your actual use-case, otherwise the chances to be trapped into an XY-problem are too high. ->

Comment: -> (Since Less is not a scripting language, it's quite common pitfall when one attempts to use non-Less-friendly design patterns from scripting languages (e.g. JavaScript) and thus has to simulate scripting-like behaviour hence stacking various kludges and workarounds on top of each other to solve a problem, which otherwise (not always but quite often) is much easier to be solved via native Less (or in general case "whatever declarative") design-patterns.)

Comment: Sure I know that less is not a scripting language. I just hoped that there is an option to build mixins with an array in the params or if that doesnot work there is any function to  get an easier if condition using less. In my opinion after your helpful comments, I recognized that there is no other, more elegant solution. Thanks either :)

Comment: Well, it's your decision :) (personally I can't see why there all those separate conditions and mixins are there at all and how and why they are supposed to be connected to arrays... And because of that I always suspect it's an XY-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
.height(@param: @_tablet_slider_-height){

      @active : false;

      & when(isnumber(@param)){
        height: @param * 1px;
        @active: true;
      }
      & when(isunit(@param)){
        height: @param;
        @active: true;
      }

      & when(ispixel(@param)){
        height: @param;
        @active: true;
      }

      & when(isem(@param)){
        height: @param;
        @active: true;
      }
      & when(ispercentage(@param)){
        height: @param;
        @active: true;
      }

      & when(@active = false){

        &:before{
          content:"Error in parsing less"
        }

      }  
}
```

Comment: Actually the code has a bug. Rulesets (including `& {}`) does not expose their content to an outer scope... Thus `@active` variable you set with `& {}` won't have any affect for the last one (thus it's always `false` there)... You'll have to use mixins instead... Though considering that there're other methods to simplify the whole thing: [an example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/1f011b11a87e8638f36a#file-31158356-less) you don't need any `@active` at all.

Comment: *More over*: for this particular snippet I wonder if you need all those conditions *at all* ;) Notice that `1 * 1px` will always result in `1px` and `1anythingelse * 1px` will also always result in `1anythingelse ` (and if one of the multiply operands is not a number Less will throw a error automatically). In other words the "better solution" is as simple as: `height: @whatever * 1px`; No need for conditions or mixin at all! (now you can guess why I complain about XY-problem every time :).

Comment: (There're a lot of use-cases for complex conditions in Less too - [a nice example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746138/2712740) - but above one is definitely is not one of those).