# LESS: define variables with conditionals

Tags: css, less

I am trying to set some internal variables inside a LESS function

```
.my-function() {
  @myVar: 5px when (@other > 1);
  @myVar: 4px when (@other = 1);
  height: @myVar;
}
```

I ask because LESS documentation only specifies conditionals as mixins functions, nothing close to what I actually "think" I need.

Comment: Mixin is the thing to use: [example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40other%3A%2033%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.my-function()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-function()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-()%20when%20(%40other%20%3E%201)%20%7B%40my-var%3A%205px%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-()%20when%20(%40other%20%3D%201)%20%7B%40my-var%3A%204px%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20height%3A%20%40my-var%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20%5C%22.-%5C%22%20it's%20just%20a%20mixin%20name%2C%20can%20be%20%5C%22.whatever%5C%22%22%7D).

Comment: Ah right, so the mixin is the only way to do. Thanks

Comment: In many cases it vastly depends on the particular use-case, for instance for your particular snippet above an easier example could look [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40other%3A%2033%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.my-function()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-function()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40other%20%3E%201)%20%7Bheight%3A%205px%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40other%20%3D%201)%20%7Bheight%3A%204px%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D). But yes, for "isolated abstract conditional structure", a mixin is what one starts with ([demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746138)).